# Show that $\omega^2+1$ is a prime number.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $\omega^2+1$ is a prime number.

Is there easy way to show it? I tried, as a warm up, to show that $(\omega+1)\omega\neq \omega^2+1$ and I failed. I am pretty sure I miss something trivial here.

$\gamma$ is a prime number iff for any $\alpha,\beta<\gamma$ we have $\alpha\beta\neq\gamma$

$\omega$ is first infinite ordinal number.

Comment: What is a "prime" ordinal number?

Comment: @coffeemath, prime number is such number that you cannot write it as a result of multiplication of two smaller numbers

Comment: @coffeemath, that's not true. We have numbers of the form $\omega\cdot n_1+n_2$ where $n_1,n_2$ are finite. $\omega^2$ is also smaller then $\omega^2+1$

Comment: Sekstus-- Yes. deleting comment.

Comment: Is there any reason why you believe that $\omega^2 + 1$ should be prime?

Comment: @Hurkyl, in exercise it is stated that it is a prime number.

Comment: $\omega^2 + 1$ has a largest element. A product $\alpha\cdot \beta$ has a largest element if and only if both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have a largest element. So if you can write $\omega^2 + 1$ as a nontrivial product, it will be of the form $(\gamma + 1)\cdot (\delta + 1)$ with $\gamma,\delta > 0$. What more can you deduce about $\gamma$? Then, what follows about $\delta$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, If what you have written is true, then I can take it from there. But to my mind, $(\omega+1)\omega$ also has the largest element. I do not see that I am wrong here.

Comment: Based on these comments I’m forced to conclude that my answer is wrong. I would appreciate if someone could point out where my misconception is.

Comment: What would be the largest element of $(\omega + 1)\omega$? Say it's $(\alpha,m)$. But $(\alpha,m+1) > (\alpha,m)$. (cc @StellaBiderman)

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks, I can see it now!

Comment: I voted to reopen the question, because I find it to be perfectly clear, as well as interesting. Is the ordinal $\omega^2+1$ prime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proof of the lemma you don’t know how to prove:

> **Lemma:**$$(\omega+1)\omega=\omega^2$$

Taking my definition of multiplication from [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic), we consider a grid of points that is laid out as $\omega+1$ from left to right and as $\omega$ from top to bottom. We assign this grid a lexicographical order such that if two points are in different rows, the lower point is larger and if two points are in the same row, the right-most point is larger.

Since each row is arranged as $\omega+1$, there is a unique last element in every row. Call this element $k_\alpha$ when it appears in row $\alpha$.

Now rearrange the grid by taking $k_\alpha$ and moving it from being the last element of row $\alpha$ and instead make it the first element of row $s(\alpha)$. We claim that this doesn’t change the order type of the grid because $k_\alpha$ remains greater than every other element in any row below row $s(\alpha)$ and less than any other element in any row above row $\alpha$.

However, this new arrangement is precisely an $\omega\times\omega$ grid, so it has order type $\omega^2$. Thanks JDH for helping me see this.

Comment: $(\omega+1)\omega$ is $\omega^2$, not $\omega^2+1$, because it means $\omega$ many copies of $\omega+1$, and so there is no last copy of $\omega+1$ to contribute the final $1$.

Comment: @JDH thanks! I’ve converted my answer into a proof of teh OP’s lemma.

Comment: And what is $(\omega+1)^2$, then?

Comment: $(\omega+1)^2$ means $\omega+1$ many copies of $\omega+1$. The first $\omega$ many copies gives $\omega^2$, as we have point out, and then one more copy makes $\omega^2+\omega+1$.

Answer (score 8):

To see that ordinal $\omega^2+1$ is prime, suppose that we could factor it as $\omega^2+1=\alpha\beta$, with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both less than $\omega^2+1$. It is fairly easy to see that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must also be less than $\omega^2$, and so bounded by $\omega\cdot n$ for some $n$.

If $\beta$ is finite, then since $\alpha<\omega\cdot n$ for some finite $n$, we'd have $\alpha\beta<\omega^2$, so this won't work.

So $\beta$ must be infinite. If $\alpha$ is finite, then $\alpha\beta<\alpha\omega\cdot n=\omega\cdot n<\omega^2$, since $\alpha\omega=\omega$ for finite $\alpha$.

So they are both infinite. Note that neither of them can be a limit ordinal, since if one of them was a limit ordinal, then $\alpha\beta$ would also be a limit ordinal, which it isn't.

So they are both at least $\omega+1$. Consequently, $\alpha\beta$ is at least $(\omega+1)(\omega+1)$, which is equal to $\omega^2+\omega+1$, which is larger than $\omega^2+1$.

So $\omega^2+1$ is prime.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's just look at the possible products of the form $(\omega i+j)(\omega k+l)$ with finite $i,j,k,l$. It is obvious that we only can get something involving $\omega^2$ is $i\ne 0$ and $k\ne 0$, therefore in the following, both are assumed.

First we have distributivity of the left factor over the right one, therefore
$$(\omega i+j)(\omega k+l) = (\omega i + j)\omega k + (\omega i + j)l$$
Next, we have
$$(\omega i + j)l = \begin{cases}
\omega i + j + \omega i + j + \ldots + \omega i + j = \omega il + j & l\ne 0\\
0 & l = 0
\end{cases}$$
or using the Kronecker delta
$$(\omega i + j)l = \omega il + j(1-\delta_{l0})$$
Further we have
$$(\omega i + j)\omega = \sup_{n<\omega} (\omega i + j) n = \sup_{n<\omega} (\omega i n + j) = \omega^2$$
and therefore
$$(\omega i + j)\omega k = \omega^2 k$$
Putting it all together, we therefore get
$$(\omega i+j)(\omega k+l) = \omega^2k + \omega i l + j = \omega^2 k + \omega i l + j$$
Now we want
$$(\omega i+j)(\omega k+l) = \omega^2 k + \omega i l + j(1-\delta_{l0}) \stackrel!= \omega^2+1$$
Then we obviously need
$$\begin{aligned}
k &= 1\\
i l &= 0\\
j(1-\delta_{l0}) &= 1
\end{aligned}$$
Since $i\ne 0$, the second equation reduces to $l=0$. However this means the third equation reduces to $0=1$ which is of course a contradiction.

Therefore $\omega^2+1$ cannot be written as product.

Comment: For some reason, I don't see our exchange concerning your answer---what happened to our comments?

Comment: @JDH: I have no idea. Maybe a moderator decided to delete them since they were attached to another answer.